Trying to create postgres database for airflow, but the postgresql dose not create database
Trying to set up a fresh airflow environment.
Installed Postgre (14), create user.
when I try to create the database with
CREATE DATABASE airflow; 
It does nothing and idling in the cml.
I checked that there is no database called airflow yet.
Here is environment:
psql (14.11 (Ubuntu 14.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1))

How are you executing this SQL? How do you know that the database has not been created?

postgres=# create database airflow_db

and I use \l that list all my existing dbs which are those default ones.

You need the semi colon at the end of the create statement.
